# How to create single web service class for Soap and Rest call with multipart in Apache cxf?

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, cxf

I have created file upload Rest and Soap base web service using Apache CXF and spring. For this i have created two different endpoints and web service classes.
Below are details of my code.

**For Rest Call**

```
@Path("/fileservice")
@WebService
public interface FileuploadSample {

@POST
@Path("/upload/text")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@WebMethod(operationName="uploadTextFile")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String uploadTextFile(MultipartBody multipartBody, @Context   HttpServletRequest request);
}  

@Service("fileService")
public class FileServiceImpl implements FileuploadSample {

public static final String UPLOAD_FILE_SERVER = "G:\\env\\Xyymm_Workspace\\upload\\";

@Override
public String uploadTextFile(MultipartBody multipartBody, HttpServletRequest request) {

    System.out.println("=======> uploadTextFile called");

    List<Attachment> attachments = multipartBody.getAllAttachments();
    for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
        DataHandler dataHandler = attachment.getDataHandler();
        try{
            // get filename to be uploaded
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> multivaluedMap = attachment.getHeaders();
            String fileName = getFileName(multivaluedMap);

            // write & upload file to server
            InputStream inputStream = dataHandler.getInputStream();
            writeToFileServer(inputStream, fileName);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
        }
    }
    return "upload success";
}


   private void writeToFileServer(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) {
   System.out.println("=======> writeToFileServer called");
   OutputStream outputStream = null;
   try {
       outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(UPLOAD_FILE_SERVER + fileName));
       int read = 0;
       byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
       while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
           outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
       }
       outputStream.flush();
       outputStream.close();
   }
   catch (IOException ioe) {
       ioe.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally{
       //release resource, if any
   }
  }


   private String getFileName(MultivaluedMap<String, String> multivaluedMap) {
   System.out.println("=======> getFileName called");
   String[] contentDisposition = multivaluedMap.getFirst("Content-Disposition").split(";");
   for (String filename : contentDisposition) {

       if ((filename.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {
           String[] name = filename.split("=");
           String exactFileName = name[1].trim().replaceAll("\"", "");
           return exactFileName;
       }
   }
   return "unknownFile";
  }
}
```

CXF.xml details for Rest below

```
<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/rest">
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="formUrlEncodeProvider"/>
        <ref bean="jaxbProvider" />
        <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
        <ref bean="wadlProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="fileService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>       
</jaxrs:server>
```

**For Soap Call**

```
public class FileUploader
{
private String Name;
private String FileType;
private DataHandler Dfile;

public String getName()
{
  return this.Name;
}

public void setName(String Name)
{
  this.Name = Name;
}

public DataHandler getDfile()
{
  return this.Dfile;
}

public void setDfile(DataHandler Dfile)
{
  this.Dfile = Dfile;
}

public String getFileType() {
    return FileType;
}

public void setFileType(String FileType) {
    this.FileType = FileType;
}
}

@WebService
public interface UploadSEI {
  void uploadFile(@WebParam(name="Dfile") FileUploader Dfile);
}

@WebService(endpointInterface = "uk.co.xcordis.xea.webservice.UploadSEI",
    serviceName = "UploadService")
public class UploadServiceImpl implements UploadSEI{

public void uploadFile(FileUploader Dfile) {

    DataHandler handler = Dfile.getDfile();
    try {

        InputStream is = handler.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("G:\\env\\Xyymm_Workspace\\upload\\"+ Dfile.getName() +"."+Dfile.getFileType()));
        byte[] b = new byte[100000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

CXF.xml details for soap

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="uploadfile" implementor="uk.co.xcordis.xea.webservice.UploadServiceImpl" address="/filesoap">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="true"/>
    </jaxws:properties> 
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Both the web service is working fine.

Now I want to make a common web service class for the both Soap and Rest web services. I have try to use **DataHandler** in the Rest Service class but that will throws the **No message body** exception. I have also try too use **MultipartBody** in both Rest and Soap web services but I got the error in the Soap call. I have also try the **Attachment** in the Soap web service but that also not work for me.

Is this thing possible single web Service class for both the request soap and rest?

How can i achieve this thing?